# How to use an SQL JOIN

Tags: sql, join

```
Table A 
(id, name)
1  | alice
2  | bob

Table B
(a_id, last_name)
1    | in wonderland
```

I want to know the SQL query (using joins) to get the result of "items in A that are not connected to B"

```
a.2|a.bob
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A left outer join will join two tables and return nulls for the second table in the JOIN if there is not a row that matches the join condition.  After that you just specify a filter in your WHERE clause indicating that you want only records where the joined table records are null.

```
SELECT A.id
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
    ON B.a_id = A.id
WHERE B.a_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select a.name, b.last_name
from a left outer join b on a.id = b.a_id
where b.a_id is null
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT A.id,A.name FROM A WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE a_id=A.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't join here:

```
SELECT id, name FROM A WHERE id not in (SELECT a_id FROM b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, name 
  FROM Table_A 
EXCEPT 
SELECT id, name 
  FROM Table_A 
       INNER JOIN Table_B    
          ON id = a_id;
```

---

It appears from the accepted answer that the projection of `name` isn't required, therefore the above may be simplified:

```
SELECT id
  FROM Table_A 
EXCEPT 
SELECT id
  FROM Table_B;
```

Comment: This solution incurs an additional table scan, sort, and nested loop.  It ends up being 3 times as expensive to execute as a LEFT OUTER JOIN and personally I find it a lot harder to comprehend.

Comment: @MyItchyChin: In SQL, if you don't explicitly state the join type you get an inner join.

Comment: Do you always take every spec you receive and interpret it literally based on the constraints of the technologies outlined in the spec?  Also I'm pretty sure JOINS is an invalid keyword in SQL.

Comment: For performance reasons Set operations require a distinct sort of at least one of the sets in the collection to avoid redundant scans and cursor resetting, I'm speaking to set theory not individual DB implementations.  That distinct sort is what's killing the performance on your solution and even in your revised solution.  WHERE clauses and JOIN conditions are filters applied during the  scan/seek that occur in any query and thus the overhead is significantly less.

Comment: Also your revised solution is not out of spec because it doesn't have a JOIN.

Comment: @MyItchyChin: "Set theory" and "distinct sort" are mutally exclusive ;) SQL's `EXCEPT` is based on the **relational** operator 'minus'. Both the relational model and Standard SQL are deliberately silent on how a DBMS may implement operators. No doubt there are established algorithms involving sorting but it certainly isn't prescribed.

Comment: @MyItchyChin: Now, if your SQL product of choice knows how to optimize "WHERE clauses and JOIN conditions" then why doesn't it transform my query accordingly? ...penny drops: ours are not semantically equivalent because yours can return duplicate rows i.e. is non-relational, all bets are off!